# Is there a more elegant way to write this batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to scripting/programming, as in this is the first script I've ever written.  I run a computer repair business and I've always wanted a simply, automated way to search out and back up all browser bookmark files on a hard drive.  This is a work in progress but before I commit to the rabbit hole I've just discovered(I cannot believe this works), I wanted to check in for a "best practices" sanity check.

I'd love it if instead of relying on the user to correctly type the User folder, thus setting the path variable, It makes more sense that the choices be numbered and the user need only enter an integer.

Thanks in advance for any criticism given!

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
dir c:\Users /B /A:D
echo.
set /p myDir="Please choose a user account from the above list: "
echo.
mkdir c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks
if exist "C:\Users\%myDir%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" (mkdir c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\Edge & copy "C:\Users\%myDir%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\Edge & echo. & echo Edge Bookmarks Copied.)
if exist "c:\Users\%myDir%\Appdata\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" (mkdir c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\Brave & copy "c:\Users\%myDir%\Appdata\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\Brave & echo. & echo Brave Bookmarks Copied.)
if exist "c:\Users\%myDir%\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" (mkdir c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\Chrome & copy "c:\Users\%myDir%\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" c:\Users\%myDir%\Desktop\Bookmarks\chrome & echo. & echo Chrome Bookmarks Copied.)   
echo.
echo.
echo.   
cscript MessageBox.vbs "ALl TaSKs ComPlETe!"
```

Comment: User profile do not have to be in the directory `C:\Users`, though they mostly are…

Answer (score 1):

There's not really much in your code to optimise, so here's a method to provide a self-adjusting menu for user-selection.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

:: FOR /f "delims=:" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad C:\users ^|findstr /n . ') DO SET "#%%b=%%c" & SET /a #users=%%b
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b IN ('findstr /n . "q72165170.txt"') DO SET "#%%b=%%c" & SET /a #users=%%b
SET /a #offset=0

:selection
SET /a #start=#offset + 1
SET /a #end=#offset + 9
IF %#end% gtr %#users% SET /a #end=#users
CLS
:: any fixed waffle goes here
SET "#choices="
FOR /L %%e IN (%#start%,1,%#end%) DO (
 SET /a #line=%%e + 1 - #START
 ECHO !#line!.....!#%%e!
 SET "#choices=!#choices!!#line!"
)
:: Add "B" for back, "M" for more and "Q" for quit to choices
SET "#message=%#choices%"
IF %#offset% neq 0 SET "#choices=%#choices%B"&SET "#message=%#message% Back"
IF %#end% lss %#users% SET "#choices=%#choices%M"&SET "#message=%#message% More"
SET "#choices=%#choices%Q"&SET "#message=%#message% Quit :"
choice /c %#choices% /n /m "%#message%"
SET /a #chosen=%ERRORLEVEL%
SET /a #index=#chosen - 1
SET "#choice=!#choices:~%#index%,1!"
IF /i "%#choice%"=="Q" GOTO :eof
IF /i "%#choice%"=="M" SET /a #offset+=9&GOTO selection
IF /i "%#choice%"=="B" SET /a #offset-=9&GOTO selection
SET /a #chosen+=#offset
ECHO !#%#chosen%! was chosen

GOTO :EOF
```

I've commented-out your `dir` command an read a file instead for testing. No doubt you'd want to use a `findstr /v` to remove user `Public` before the `findstr /n`.

First, clear out all variables starting `#`.

Next, well - in OP's case, number the lines delivered by `dir` using `findstr /n` which prefixes each line with *sequencenumber*: Use `tokens` and `delimiters=:` to assign the line number to `%%b` and the text to `%%c`. Record these in environment variable `#`*`??`* where `??` is a number.

Then the main loop. Giving the user a choice of `9` options (1 to 9, duh) set the start of the options presented as `#offset`

Display each option and accumulate options in `#choices`.

Since there may be more than  9 data items to display, allow `M` if there are more options (`M` simply moves `#offset`) and `B` (reverses `M`) and `Q` to quit.

Display the choices and wait for the user.
Using `errorlevel` returned by `choice`, calculate the actual character used. Add the offset if it was not [BMQ] and display the choice made. If [BMQ], take the logical action.